# Ruby On Rails - Datetime Range issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date-range

Using an API, i can retrieve an orders list from a website.

in this list, i have for each order, the date of presentation.

i need to filter this list for order placed in a specific range, but using the date range i have "bad value for range"

this is how the API present the date:

```
"date_created"=>"2017-03-08T11:22:00"
```

This is my code

```
@lunedi = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
@martedi = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week + 1
ele_ordini = woocommerce.get("orders").parsed_response
@ele_ordini = ele_ordini.select { |ordine| ordine['date_created'] == lunedi.to_datetime..martedi.to_datetime }
```

My goal si to filter for order placed in current week, only on Monday and Tuesday

yes, the code must be changed ot fill all Tuesday day until 23:59!! but i can do it after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to use active record notation which doesn't work with the `select` method. Something like this should work.

```
@ele_ordini = ele_ordini.select do |ordine| 
  tmp = ordine['date_created'].to_datetime
  tmp >= lunedi.to_datetime && tmp <= martedi.to_datetime
end
```

Comment: Great! Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just care about comparing the dates (and you're using Rails - which it looks like you are), then you could simplify this somewhat. For example:

```
@lunedi = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
ele_ordini = woocommerce.get("orders").parsed_response
@ele_ordini = ele_ordini.select { |ordine| ordine['date_created'].to_date - @lunedi < 2 }
```

i.e. you're only looking at the difference in days between each date and Monday, and selecting anything that is 0 (Monday) or 1 (Tuesday)

Answer (score 0):

You need to state the unit of time when adding it to a variable. Try this

```
@lunedi = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
@martedi = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week + 1.day
ele_ordini = woocommerce.get("orders").parsed_response
@ele_ordini = ele_ordini.select { |ordine| (lunedi..martedi).include? ordine['date_created'] }
```